# How to access files of public folder in Laravel and Linux OS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Linux can't find the css, js etc. files which are placed in public folder.

I am using this code to access my files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/styles.css') }}">
```

And it is giving an error like this:

[image: Error screenshot]

But on windows exactly the same project is working fine.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: try this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('styles.css') }}">`

Answer (score 0):

[Create the symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#configuration) by executing: `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this will be execute. no need to url facade.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">
```